# Most installed packages marked obsolete in aptitude, updates are not found

Tags: debian, aptitude

I was running aptitude and previewing packages marked to be updated when the power went out for a second. Now almost all of my installed packages are marked as obsolete and the updates I was about to install aren't found anymore. Updating the package list doesn't have any effect.

I assume I need to delete some file in the apt cache so that the package lists are downloaded anew.
Is this assumption right? If yes, which file would I need to get rid of? If no, what do I need to do instead to repair my dpkg/apt?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists/` and updating the apt package lists via

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo rm -rv ./*
sudo apt update
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: For future reference you just need to run `apt-get update`, nothing more, it will re-download all the archive indexes and process them. Also if you are doing a lot of work as root, you can become root by simply running `sudo su -` and then `exit` at the end of your admin session. To resume the install `apt-get -f install` will finish any broken or partial installs that were interrupted.

Comment: @HostFission No, I tried that first and that didn't help in any way. Look in the original question: "Updating the package list doesn't have any effect."

Comment: @ThomasBartscher Then your apt install itself is broken, apt-get update replaces those files, just take a look at the source.

Comment: Hm, yes, that does seem like something that might happen when apt is disrupted in the middle of updating.